# Visual Studio files in Git

Tags: git, visual-studio, repository, visual-studio-2017, projects-and-solutions

I'm new to Visual Studio and using VS2017.
Which Visual Studio project-files (like myproject.sln, etc.) should I check into Git to keep the configuration (include directories, linker options, etc.) when checking out on a different machine? Should I check in the full .vs/ directory? It's very big (2GB for some reason, although my repo is only 80MB) and I don't wan't a big repository, if avoidable.

Thank you for your answers

Comment: Of-course you should keep .sln file in repository. It will help reopen the project using solution file. But directories like `bin, obj,    packages, .vs` should not be pushed to repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your answers are in this `.gitignore` file that you should use :

https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore